# Retrofit - subdomain and directory

Tags: android, networking, retrofit

For the server I'm using, we have a subdomain and a directory both tied together. With Retrofit, you need to specify the baseURL and it doesn't seem to allow directories. Is there a way I can implement this?

Example:

- https://dev.myserver.com/myserver_dev/api/user/login...
- https://qa.myserver.com/myserver_qa/api/user/login...

I've tried:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dev.myserver.com/myserver_dev")
            .build();
```

...

```
@POST("user/login" )
Call<NewUser> login( @Query( "email" ) String email, @Query( "password" ) String password );
```

but it always give me a 404 saying "Not Found". It only seems to work if I do:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dev.myserver.com")
            .build();
```

...

```
@POST("server_dev/user/login" )
Call<NewUser> login( @Query( "email" ) String email, @Query( "password" ) String password );
```

Mainly I would just like to be able to quickly switch servers without having to manually edit two different fields. (One for baseUrl and one for the directory.)

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears retrofit ignores the path component of the `baseUrl` unless it ends in a trailing slash.

Try --

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dev.myserver.com/myserver_dev/")
            .build();
```

By the way, there is an issue filed on this already -- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1049

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Dynamic Urls or Passing a Full Url](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-url-handling-resolution-and-parsing)

```
# Example 3 — completely different url
base url: http://futurestud.io/api/  
endpoint: https://api.futurestud.io/  
Result:   https://api.futurestud.io/

# Example 4 — Keep the base url’s scheme
base url: https://futurestud.io/api/  
endpoint: //api.futurestud.io/  
Result:   https://api.futurestud.io/

# Example 5 — Keep the base url’s scheme
base url: http://futurestud.io/api/  
endpoint: //api.github.com  
Result:   http://api.github.com
```

In your case:

```
String SCHEME = "https:";
String SERVER_URL= "//{subdomain}.myserver.com/myserver_dev/";
String BASE_URL= SCHEME + BASE_URL;
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();

@POST(SERVER_URL + "user/login")
    Observable<NewUser> createNewUser(@Path("subdomain") String subdomain, @QueryMap HashMap<String, String> params);
```

Call:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
     params.put("email",email);
     params.put("pass",pass);
Observable<NewUser>  observable = mApiService.createNewUser("dev",params);
```